# Using express middleware in Sails.js to serve static files

Tags: node.js, static, sails.js, middleware

I have trouble using the express middleware on sails 0.11.0. I tried the following in http.js file.

```
module.exports.http = {

  customMiddleware: function (app) {
    console.log("middleware");
    app.use('/test', express.static('****/****/*****/testProject/api/controllers' + '/public/'));
  }

};
```

But it doesn't work, I am missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the latest Sails (0.12), calling express-style `app.use(...)` isn't directly possible from `config/http.js` (or as a policy) because the custom middleware function parameters changed from `function (app)` to `function (req, res, next)`. This is probably why some of the answers here don't work with Sails 0.12.

This change isn't clearly mentioned in Sails documentation and migration guides, but looking at [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application), we see that `app.use(...)` can accept a single `function (req, res, next)` argument... so my guess was to assign the parameter to `app.use(...)` as a custom middleware in `config/http.js` like so (using [connect-history-api-fallback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-history-api-fallback) as an example):

```
// config/http.js
var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

module.exports.http = {
  middleware: {
    order: [
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      'myRequestLogger',
      'bodyParser',
      'handleBodyParserError',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'poweredBy',
      '$custom',
      'router',
      'connectHistoryApiFallback', // <==
      'www',
      'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
    ],
  },

  // Do this instead of app.use(history())
  connectHistoryApiFallback: history()
}
```

And voilà, it works like a charm!

**TL;DR** Since Sails 0.12, custom middlewares defined in `config/http.js` should be of the type `function (req, res, next)` and not `function (app)`, so instead of calling `app.use(someMiddleware)`, you should place `someMiddleware` directly in `sails.config.http.middleware.order`.

Comment: app.use(someMiddleware) is all nice and good, but how do we add custom paths like app.use('/docs', express.static(process.cwd() + '/docs'));

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is a little off and you need to return the execution from the provided call back. It should look just like a controller.action.

I'm including the example from docs, this should help you

```
/**
 * HTTP Server Settings
 * (sails.config.http)
 *
 * Configuration for the underlying HTTP server in Sails.
 * Only applies to HTTP requests (not WebSockets)
 *
 * For more information on configuration, check out:
 */

module.exports.http = {


    order: [
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      'myRequestLogger',
      'bodyParser',
      'handleBodyParserError',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'poweredBy',
      '$custom',
      'router',
      'www',
      'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
    ],

    myRequestLogger: function (req, res, next) {
        console.log("Requested :: ", req.method, req.url);
        return next();
    }

};
```

Comment: Using that example to check if the middleware works, I am not able to log the GET/POST requests I do. Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post a link to your code via paste bin or something?

Comment: Here is the code in http.js file : http://pastebin.com/sJBNxSQv. And here is an example of code of a controller : http://pastebin.com/A12r2S79

Comment: fixed : after looking at the docs, the following syntax is the right one => middleware: { myRequestLogger: function ....}

Comment: I fixed the logging request middleware but I can't get the express middleware working. I thought, reading the doc, that I would be able to use the old system declaring the middleware outside of the middleware brackets : http://pastebin.com/8hMhEXLn

Comment: You will want to declare it inside the middleware brackets, but it is also being overridden by the "www" middleware. http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Middleware

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Sails 0.12. Modified the *config/http.js* and added the following:

```
/**
 * HTTP Server Settings
 * (sails.config.http)
 *
 * Configuration for the underlying HTTP server in Sails.
 * Only applies to HTTP requests (not WebSockets)
 *
 * For more information on configuration, check out:
 * http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.http.html
 */

var express = require('../node_modules/sails/node_modules/express');

module.exports.http = {

  middleware: {
      // middleware code here ...
  },

  customMiddleware: function(app){
    app.use('/', express.static(process.cwd() + '/assets'));
    return app.use('/bower_components', express.static(process.cwd() + '/bower_components'));
  }
};
```

Allowed me to do SPP without any engine nor use another http server to serve the static content.

Answer (score 1):

On sails 0.12.13 `function (app)` still works, just pay attention where you place the middleware code (config/http.js):

```
/**
 * HTTP Server Settings
 * (sails.config.http)
 */

var express = require('express')

module.exports.http = {

  middleware: {

    order: [
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      // 'customMiddleware', --> NOT NEEDED
      'bodyParser',
      'handleBodyParserError',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'poweredBy',
      '$custom',
      'router',
      'www',
      'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
    ],

  },

  customMiddleware: function (app) {
    // this code will be executed only once during the application startup
    app.use('/public', express.static('/etc'));
  }
};
```

After doing this you should be able to access the password file in your system using this URL: http://localhost:1337/public/passwd

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: Sails change since i wrote this answer, please, look if @Meeker answer works.

** OLD ANSWER **

This work for me:

```
var express = require('express');

module.exports.http = {

  customMiddleware: function (app) {
    app.use('/', express.static(process.cwd() + '/assets/site'));
  },

  middleware: {

    order: [
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cookieParser',
      'customMiddleware',
      'session',
      'myRequestLogger',
      'bodyParser',
      'handleBodyParserError',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'poweredBy',
      '$custom',
      'router',
      'www',
      'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
    ],
```

Comment: does anybody knows how make this in 0.12?