# Sails.js - Serving sails route via express middleware

Tags: javascript, express, routes, sails.js

I have a sails app and the routes,static assets associated with the app are served from root and it works fine. I would like to add a express middleware so i could serve the routes and static assets in a specific path.

In order to serve the static assets i used the below inside the customMiddleware function in config/http.js,

```
app.use('/my/new/path', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client', 'dist')));
```

With the above in place i was able to load the static files both from the root as well as from the /my/new/path.

Now when it comes to route i'm not sure how to handle the sails route to load via express middleware using app.use, for example the home route defaults to '/' in my config/routes-client.js, instead of altering the route there i would like to use something like below which we normally use for a typical node/express app,

```
app.use('/my/new/path', routes); --> where routes is my server routes
```

Is there a way to add a express middleware to serve sails route on a specific path?

Comment: Check [Using express middleware in Sails.js to serve static files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41604077/3058802)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd want to have a prefix added automatically to your custom routes rather than just adding the prefix directly to the routes in the `config/routes.js` (or `config-routes-client.js`) file, but here goes:

```
// config/http.js
middleware: {
  reroute: function (req, res, next) {
    // Set the prefix you want for routes.
    var prefix = '/foo/bar';
    // Create a regex that looks for the prefix in the requested URL.
    var regex = new RegExp('^' + prefix + '(/|$)');
    // If the prefix is found, replace it with /
    if (req.url.match(regex)) {
      req.url = req.url.replace(regex, '/');
    }
    // Continue processing the request.
    return next();
  }
}
```

Make sure you add `reroute` to the `middleware.order` array in `config/http.js`.  Incidentally, this will take care of static files as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it...

Inside http.js

```
var express = require('express');

    module.exports.http = {
        customMiddleware: function (app) {
            app.use('/docs', express.static(path.join(sails.config.appPath, '/docs')));
        },

    ... rest of the http.js code...
    }
```

Of course in this example im serving docs folder from root of my app on route /docs... You addapt to your logic...

Comment: The OP already has static routes covered; they're asking specifically about how to add a path prefix to _non_-static routes (i.e. Sails actions).